# Securing SharedPreferences support for all types

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I store sensitive date in my android app SharedPreferences.

1. I have extensive use of all kinds of put and get (PutLong, PutDouble...)
2. My app is already at production how can I find a solution which will not demage existing users when upgrading?

What i need:

1. I saw secure-prefs library on GitHub but it only support String put and get, I need to support all methods.
2. How can I stamp the SP one time so if the user manually change the file I can detect it?

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with your implementation of secure pref - you can use something like SQLite in conjunction with encryption, or you can fork the github project to add support for long/int.

For migration, you can just load all your prefs and put them into the new secure pref store. there is a getAll() method on Android's SharedPreference. I don't think we you need check for timestamp.